# Is there away of Reloading(Refreshing)Django Server automatically without using Ctrl +s or even Ctlrl +c and then runing it again

Tags: django, server, reloading

I have Managed to build a web hosting platform using django i intend to make the platform free webhosting platform but the problem i have is that my django server needs to reload from time to time .i have tried the following options bellow.

```
import time
import schedule 
import keyboard 
from threading import *
from datetime import datetime
import django 
from django.utils import autoreload  

class ExitCommand(Exception):
    pass
def load():
    try:
        django.setup()   
        keyboard.press_and_release("Ctrl+c") 
        autoreload.autoreload_started 
        autoreload.DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV
        autoreload.file_changed
        run=autoreload.StatReloader() 
        run.should_stop=False
        run.run_loop() 
        print("Server changes detected")
        now=autoreload.get_reloader()
        now.notify_file_changed(os.path.join(BASE_DIR))  
        raise ExitCommand()  
    except ExitCommand:
           keyboard.press_and_release("Ctrl+s")   
        #  autoreload.autoreload_started 
        #  autoreload.get_reloader()  
        #  autoreload.DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV
        #  autoreload.raise_last_exception()                         
        #  autoreload.iter_all_python_module_files()
        #  autoreload.restart_with_reloader() 
           os.system("python manage.py runserver 8080")  
           print("++Reloading Server+++") 



def relaod_server():
    load_time="22:59:00"
    now=datetime.now()
    current_time=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    start_time=datetime.strptime(load_time,"%H:%M:%S")
    stop_time=datetime.strptime(current_time,"%H:%M:%S")
    time_diffrence=start_time-stop_time  
    os.environ["RELOAD_HOURS_REMAINING"]=str(time_diffrence)
    schedule.every().day.at("23:47").do(load)            
    
    while True: 
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1) 
   

    
  




refresh=Thread(target=relaod_server,args=[])
refresh.setDaemon(True)   


refresh.start() 
`your text`

What am trying to do is to make django server reload automatically after some time kindly help,i am working on my company start up.i am working on a webhosting paltform which i have finished writing the only challange i have is that my django server needs to reload and i dont know how to do that.
```